# sql join from microsoft access table to another table through odbc using pass through query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

So i have a very large data set on a server that i need to shrink. I have a list of names in a table locally on my computer with ms access. I want to create an inner join from my small local table to this huge server table. I was thinking I would just do a pass through query in ms access and inner join the two tables, but when i do a pass through query MS access can't find my local table (it only recognizes the tables on the server). How can i join the two? Here is my current code:

```
select field1, field2
from tablea inner join tableb
on tablea.field1=tableb.field2
;
```

Comment: Three ways immediately come to mind: 1. create a stored procedure on the sql server that takes a table valued parameter or xml or similar as input, and pass your access table to the stored procedure to do the processing on the server.  2. Represent your access table as an IN statement (e.g. select * from table1 where table1.id IN (1,2,3,4)). 3. Have a working table on your server that you insert a copy of your access table to and then link to this instead.  (My favourite order: 1,3,2 (2 only if you're desperate)

Comment: thanks storm, i shared idea 2 with you haha. it's 100,000 names in my local table, so when i tried to convert it to a comma separated string and paste it in the query, it was too long to be valid. :( I'm not technical enough to understand #1, but i don't think i have permission to add a table to this server. #3 falls under permission also! so i guess no easy answer for this one? But thanks for the ideas!

Comment: Two hacks come to mind to get no.2 working.  1. Try and filter down the 100,000 names so you aren't sending so many across.  (do this anyway you can, even if it means calling the server for info to filter them down).  2. Don't do it all in one giant query, break the query up - if you have to do it in 1000 name chunks, well it's only 100 queries, it's not going to take that long if your query is efficient/there are the correct indexes on the sql server table.

Comment: Have you tried simply creating an [ODBC Linked Table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/about-importing-and-linking-data-and-database-objects-HP005241695.aspx) in the Access database that points to the table on the SQL Server and then JOIN the local table to the linked table?

Comment: yes Gord, does not work. These tables are very, very big. I'm pushing the memory limits of access. For now I'm abandoning this idea and trying to make a form so that the user can click on it and run a pass through query using the exact value that was clicked. I have not seen this question anywhere online, so please stop marking my questions as dups :)